# Api-platform (Symfony) : Add data to Url

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I've encountered a problem with Api-platform, some code that was already there when I started my job is making me angry.
Here it is :

```
/**
 * Class PhysicalProfile.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="front_user_physical_profile")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PhysicalProfileRepository")
 * @ApiResource(
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"update"}},
 *     collectionOperations={"create"={
 *          "method"="POST",
 *          "path"="/physical-profile",
 *          "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')"
 *     }, "whoami"={"route_name"="api_security_physicalprofile_whoami"}
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "get"={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')", "normalizationContext"={"groups"={"null"}}},
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
```

The thing I'd like to do is pass an element in the query like this:

```
/physical-profile/{store}
```

and then use it in my code.

Except I don't find any help in the documentation of Api-platform, making me wonder if what I want is possible.
That's why I came here, to figure if someone knows if it's possible and thus, how to do it.
Thank you !

EDIT : store is not an id but a string

Answer (score 0):

API Platform expect that in patch like `/physical-profile/{store}` last part is entity ID.

If you need query some items use [filters](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#doctrine-orm-and-mongodb-odm-filters).

Comment: Except that for me store is not an id but a string :/

Comment: What is your goal generally? Do you want GET or POST items?

Comment: I want to POST items and pass a parameter in the URL instead of the body because I don't want to store the parameter in the database

Comment: I think its appropriate using [DTO](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/#specifying-an-input-or-an-output-data-representation) with [custom controller](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers).